# If two Normal operators commute then the product is normal

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ and $S$ be two normal operators in a infinite dimensional inner-product complex vector space. If $ST=TS$, I want to show that $TS$ is normal.

For the finite-dimensional case, it went down to showing $T^*=f(T)$ for some polynomial $f$. But I have no clue on what to do on the infinite dimensional case.
This is an exercise of Hoffman's Linear Algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Fuglede's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem which ensures, in your case that $ST^*=T^*S$ and $S^*T=ST^*$.

In view of the facts that $(TS)^*=S^*T^*$, $SS^*=S^*S$ and $TT^*=T^*T$, the conclusion follows by easy computations:
$$
TS(TS)^*=T(SS^*)T^*=(TS^*)ST^*=S^*T(ST^*)=S^*(TT^*)S=(S^*T^*)TS=(TS)^*TS
$$

The property is not longer true in the unbounded case. You can follow the paper "M. H. Mortad, On the closedness, the self-adjointness and the normality of the product of two
unbounded operators, Demonstratio Math., 45 (2012), 161-167" for an example. It is also stated there that the normality of $TS$ is valid when, in addition, $S$ (or $T$) is unitary.

Comment: What if they are not bounded?

Comment: As far as I know the result is not true for unbounded operators without additional assumptions (see my edited answer).

Comment: Thank you! I'll read the reference as soon as I get to my university.

Answer (score 3):

If bounded operators $T$ and $S$ on a Hilbert space commute and $S$ is normal, then $T$ and $S^*$ commute ([Fuglede's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuglede%27s_theorem)).

Comment: What if they are not bounded?

Comment: Commutation of unbounded (densely-defined) operators can be tricky, because the domains of $TS$ and $ST$ might have non-dense (even trivial) intersection.  If you assume the spectral projections of $S$ and $T$ commute, then Fuglede's theorem should go through.